# How can I change the layoutServiceHost to be read from an environment variable?

Tags: jss

Currently the `layoutServiceHost` is read from a parameter in `scjssconfig.json`. This means that it needs to be changed and then a rebuild needs to occur for the change to take effect.
Is it possible to change this to read from an environment variable so that we don't need to rebuild?

Comment: One thing I have done in the past, was to use a text editor to do a search and replace in the dist output folder. It's ugly but works if you need to quickly do some debugging.

Comment: Option 2 in this blog post seems offering a solution to your question: https://blog.vitaliitylyk.com/devops-with-sitecore-jss-configuration-management/

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you want the `layoutServiceHost` to be, but it's not mandatory. If you remove the `layoutServiceHost` parameter it will use the current host it's on. So that is also an option.

Comment: This isn't working for me - I get an error Network error: Only absolute URLs are supported
Error
   at new ApolloError

Comment: It seems you'd need custom code to get this to work

Comment: Sorry I didn't try it with Apollo. I'm using it with Axios and there it works.

Answer (score 0):

The JSS team have an answer [here](https://github.com/Sitecore/jss/issues/416) which outlines how to use environment variable and a .env file to move JSS config out of code.
However, you still need to build the application and the environment variables of the build will be used.